# JS Promise inside a method

Tags: ecmascript-6, promise, firebase-authentication

I have a method which signs in a user through firebase with a promise. I have a promise, when its finish, with then, I get the token.

```
signinUser(email: string, password: string) {
    return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(
            response => {
                this.router.navigate(['/']);
                firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()
                    .then(
                        (token: string) => {
                            this.token = token
                        }
                    )
            }
        )
        .catch(
            error => console.log(error)
        );
}
```

Now, I call the method from another file, and I want to do something once the signinUser method is done with its promise

```
  onSignin(form: NgForm) {
    const email = form.value.email;
    const password = form.value.password;
    this.authService.signinUser(email, password)
      .then(
        res => console.log(res)
      )

  }
```

I am getting as res (result) undefined. Why?

Comment: What are you expecting `res` to be? A `token`? The `.then` callback of `signInWithEmailAndPassword` never returns a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning token from the promise

```
signinUser(email: string, password: string) {
    return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((response) => {
            this.router.navigate(['/']);
            return firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()
                .then((token: string) => {
                    this.token = token
                    return token;
                })
        })
        .catch(
            error => console.log(error)
        );
}
```

Comment: why if i do: signinUser(email: string, password: string): Promise<string | void> { it works, and if i get rid of the void, it doesn't work.

i know that i get back a string, the token

the error is the following: Type 'Promise<string | void>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<string>'.